# How do i send data from my esp8266 light sensor to blynk?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, blynk

I am trying to know whether the lights have tripped using a light sensor to detect light intensity. However, i do not know how to upload my data onto blynk, as i am new to blynk and new to arduino as well. Below is my code. I tried using a telegram bot to get the data but somehow it stopped working and i am finding alternatives to get the data remotely. If there are any other methods other than Blynk please suggest too.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> // WIFI LIBRARY
#include <WiFiClient.h> //CLIENT LIBRARY  
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h> //WEBSERVICER LIBRARY
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h> //HTTP CLIENT LIBRARY

char auth[] = BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN;
char ssid[] = "ArchiEngStudio";
char pass[] = "a12345678";


int CNT = 0, sent, i, j;
float count = 0;

int limit = 800; // SET LIMIT HERE

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  float reading = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(reading);
  
  delay(3000);
  
/* NO LIGHT CONDITION */

  if (reading < limit)
  { 
    if (CNT < 1) // CHECK LOOP ONLY RUNS ONCE
    {
      count = 0;
      
      for (i=0; i<10; i++) //TAKING 10 READINGS TO CHECK IF LIGHTS ARE REALLY OFF 
      {
        delay(1000);
        int read2 = analogRead(A0);
        Serial.println(read2);
    
        if (read2 < limit)
        {
          Serial.println("(1) No Light ..."); 
        } 
        else
        {
          Serial.println("(1) Light on...");
          i= i+20;
        }
      }
       if (i < 11) // IF ALL 10 READINGS SHOW THAT LIGHTS ARE OFF, SEND MESSAGE
      {
        if (sent == 0)
        {
          Serial.println("Tripped!");
          sent = 1;
        }
      }

      
    }
    
    CNT++;
  }
      
  else
  {
    CNT = 0;
  }

/* LIGHTS ON CONDITION */

  if (sent == 1) //ONLY ALLOWED IF LIGHTS WERE OFF
    {
      if (reading >= limit)
      {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++) //TAKING 10 READINGS TO CHECK IF LIGHTS ARE REALLY ON 
        {
          delay(1000);
          int read3 = analogRead(A0);
          Serial.println(read3);
      
          if (read3 >= limit)
          {
            Serial.println("(2) Light on..."); 
          } 
          else
          {
            Serial.println("(2) No light...");
            j= i+10;
          }
        }
        if (j < 11) //IF ALL 10 READINGS SHOW THAT LIGHTS ARE ON, SEND MESSAGE
        {
          Serial.println("Light on!");
           sent = 0;
        }
        
      }
    }

 }
```

Comment: use `blynkWrite`. https://docs.blynk.io/en/getting-started/how-to-display-any-sensor-data-in-blynk-app

Answer (score 0):

Blynk provides a decent way to display your data and is very easy to use once you are familiar with the concept.

You can store your `reading` variable in a virtual pin 'Vx' on the Blynk server by adding this line to your code:

`Blynk.virtualWrite(Vx, reading);`

If you want to display it on the app just use "value display" widget and configure it to display your virtual pin 'Vx'.